# When making chrome extension, I keep getting this error: Uncaught (in promise) Error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

When making a chrome extension, I keep getting this error

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.
```

Along with

```
background.js:0 (anonymous function)
```

Does anyone know how I could resolve this? I literally have like 3 lines in both my files.

This is my background.js file

```js
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener((tabId, tab) => {
  if (tab.url && tab.url.includes("linkedin.com/in")) {
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, {type: "MAIN", profile: "test"});
  }
});
```

and This is my ContentScript.js file

```js
(() => {
    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((obj, sender, response) => {
        //const { type, profile } = obj;
        response = {line1 : "hello"}
    });
})();
```

Any help would grealy be appreciated :)

Comment: When the page loads, its content script runs after chrome.tabs.onUpdated is fired, even if declared with `"run_at": "document_start"`, so there'll be no listeners yet when you call sendMessage.
You can reverse the direction of communication and use chrome.runtime.sendMessage in the content script or open a port from the content script via chrome.runtime.connect, then use this port in the background script to notify the content script, [example](/a/61600254).